# Problem with ./configure while installing from tar

Tags: upgrade, command-line

I am trying to install a more recent version of a program than what is available via Synaptic, but I am running into a few problems. And I have one question beyond those problems. This is what I've done so far.

I downloaded the `.tar.gz2`, created a folder in `/usr/local/` for the program. Call it `app`. So I now have a folder `/usr/local/app`. Inside the folder I extracted the archive. I then navigated a terminal to that folder and ran

```
sudo apt-get build-dep app
```

It downloaded and installed several libraries and I thought I was set. However, when I ran `sh ./configure` I encountered the following problem:

```
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.14.0... 
'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.14.0, but GLIB (2.28.6)
was found! If pkg-config was correct, then it is best
to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error
by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing
/etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is
required on your system.
If pkg-config was wrong, set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH
to point to the correct configuration files
```

Ok, no problem. I went out and found Glib 2.14.0. I created a new folder `/usr/local/glib`. I extracted the archive to that folder. I ran the `sh ./configure` for Glib, and it went off without a hitch. I then ran make install for Glib. Again, no problems. It installed successfully. So now I was ready to rock! Back I went into `/usr/local/app`, and once again I ran `sh ./configure`. And I got the exact same error message. I am not understanding the message as it appears to say that `./configure` requires GLib version 2.14.0 or later, and it found version 2.28.6, which would more than meet the requirement. I'm not great with shell scripts so I am somewhat, well, entirely, confused as to what it is this thing wants from me.

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 on a Toshiba Satellite. As you can see I'm not exactly a terminal warrior, but I can usually scratch my way through most problems and have learned quite a bit as I go.  This one just has me stumped.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your LIBRARY PATH to the directory glib was installed to. Since it is user-built it will reside in another directory, I am not 100% sure, but my first guess is `/urs/local/lib`.

put this into your bash:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export CPATH=/usr/local/include
```

and try again, i think make install will tell you the directory. so if its another one check its output.

if you want to check how your environment variables are set type

```
echo ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

of course you can replace the name with all other variables.

you have to set those environment variables every time you fire up a new shell, but you can write it to your bash_profile, too, i think (never tried that though).

Comment: I ran the exports and the echo produced:

/usr/local/src/glib

Which is exactly where GLIB was installed so everything should have been good to go.  I then ran the ./configure again and still got the exact same message regarding GLIB.  So the system knows where it is, yet it somehow isn't finding it when I run the shell script.  I'm so confounded by this thing.

Also, I can't run make or make install.  In both cases I get the message that the make file is not found.  There is a make file in the tar, obviously.  My guess is that it won't run make until I get a successful configure.

Comment: Further clarification.  Attempting to run make yields the message "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."  Attempting to run make install gets results in "make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop."  Perhaps I am using make wrong.  This was a question for further down the road, I guess.  I am installing a newer version of an existing program.  Do I need specify that somehow when I run make or make / install?  What target do I need to give?

Comment: ok, i am not pretty sure what to do from here now. have you tried `ldconfig` maybe you need to do a make clean before. other idea i have is that you might be missing the glib-dev package. you might be able to install this via apt.

Comment: you should try installing glib-dev first.

Comment: Sounds obvious, but have you run 'sudo ldconfig -v'?

Comment: @Walter: I installed glib-dev before I started any of this.

Comment: @Christopher:  Thank you for the tip, I think.  I ran apt-cache libc6, which showed version 2.13.  This could somewhat explain the problem in that the /configure requires 2.14.  However, I am now more confused than before because nowhere in the error message does it say that it found 2.13.  It says that it found 2.38!  Also, what about my installation of 2.14?  Honestly, I have no idea where the 2.13 is coming from.  Between my installation of 2.14 and grabbing the latest glib-dev in Synaptic I should be covered.  Either way, the error should have returned that it found 2.13.

Comment: Suspecting that I may have had a bad install I went ahead and installed glib 2.30.1, which is, again, well beyond the 2.14.0 minimum requirement.  The install was fine.  I then once again tried the ./configure and got the same error as above, only where it says "returned 2.14.0" it now says "returned 2.30.1".  I still cannot understand why this is not meeting the >=2.0 requirement.  I also tried LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/src/glib-2.30.1" ./configure.  This yielded the exact same error message.  So setting the path variable does nothing for me here.

Comment: AH!  I just solved that problem only to run into another.  I ran PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/src/glib-2.30.1" ./configure and the config finished clean!  So, that hurdle was crossed.  The problem is that when I then ran make install I got just a bit into the installation before it shut down and threw the following: "uunconc.c:31:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.".  Man, this is like pulling teeth!

Comment: Ah! So you may have the right libraries, but it wants the include files. Put the glib include files somewhere in a common system path, perhaps /usr/local/include/glib